# Android App Is Causing Battery Drain

Tags: android, eclipse

I have two issues with this, my very first android app. The first is that I noticed after I installed the app the battery started draining about twice as fast as before. I read an article on this that stated sometimes programmers make an error which causes this. This being my first app, the probability is pretty high that this is the case.

The second issue is that I can save my variables when the app is turned off, but when the phone is turned off the data is lost.

As for the code, it's mostly bits and pieces from stuff I've found online and tried to incorporate. It's a simple calculator with three variables. Ideally, I'd like to store `b` and `c`, but allow the user to overwrite them. Variable `a` will change with each use, so no need to store that.

Here's my Main:

```
package com.kwagz.calc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String g, e;
String b; //changed(sorry)
String c; //changed
SharedPreferences sh_Pref;
Editor toEdit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    loadSavedPreferences();

}

public void calculateClickHandler(View view) {

 if (view.getId() == R.id.button1) {

     EditText a = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.a);
 EditText b = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.b);
 EditText c = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.c);
 TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView9);

 double gp = Double.parseDouble(a.getText().toString());
     int ab = Integer.parseInt(b.getText().toString());
     int ac = Integer.parseInt(c.getText().toString());        
     double t = ((gp / ab) * ac);

 output.setText(String.format("%.2f", t));
 }

 }

public void sharedPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences saved_values =//there's no linebreak here in my code
 PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=saved_values.edit();
         editor.putString("b", b);
         editor.putString("c", c);
         editor.commit();   

}

private void loadSavedPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences saved_values =//there's no linebreak here in my code
 PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

    b = saved_values.getString("b", g);
}


}
```

Comment: `//there's no linebreak here in my code` - it wouldn't matter if there was - that's what the semicolon is for.

Comment: Your app is just that? A battery drain is caused when an heavy operation is going, an alarmmanager, if the application turns on a sensor and bla bla bla.. but i don't see any problem here. You should go in settings > battery in your phone and see if it's really your app

Comment: I did this when I first noticed the problem and didn't even see my app listed. With the app installed, Screen was the biggest user. Without the app, my Y! Mail app is top dog. I should also mention that the phone seem to be warmer to the touch with the app installed that when I removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've conducted several tests in an effort to recreate the issue, with no success. I'm still working on the sharedPreferences thing, but the battery drain (I suspect) was caused by another app which just happened to coincide with the installation of mine.

As I mentioned in my note to arleitiss, my Y!Mail was showing the highest amount of battery drain. A day or two after posting the note my account started acting up and then became "inactive". Once I reset it, the app no longer appears on the Battery list.

Thanks for all the input!

Answer (score 0):

From reading what you said, the only logical explanation forming in my head is: You are starting background service from your App, while background service is running it makes app run all the time which explains why variables are stored until phone is turned off (when background service gets killed).

Comment: I think I figure out what the issue was, but I want to do some overnight tests to be sure. And it has nothing to do with the app ('cause I'm not requesting any services).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's take your questions one at a time. The battery problem could be a number of things, without knowing more details about your program I couldn't possibly diagnose it completely. Android does have some [good power saving tips](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/index.html). The key item is to minimize the use of connectivity devices to no more than is required. The two biggest culprits are GPS and Internet connections. If your app isn't running, then the only way it could be running the batteries is if there's threads in the background, or maybe something like an AlarmService.

You are using SharedPreferences correctly, the value should be saved, but I think you should but the saving code in [`onSaveInstanceState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29). If you do that, it should work fine.

EDIT

Upon closer inspection, you're fundementally saving the wrong thing. You should save the value of the `EditText`, not the `EditText` itself. In fact, I'd simply remove all references to `String a,b,c`, move the EditText definitions to the top to replace them, and do something like this:

```
editor.putString("b", b.getText().toString());

b.setText(saved_values.getString("b", g));
```

Comment: I moved the SharedPreferences code as suggested with the same results. Which leads me to suspect that I might be referencing the wrong variables somehow. Also, I noticed in my post that two of the Strings I declared the wrong variables, so I changed them with a notation.

Comment: I think I've got the problem, and edited my answer appropriately.

Comment: The result was "unfortunate" as the app crashed on loading. The only way to get it running was to comment out the loadSavedPreferences bit. As for the values, that's what I thought I had with ab and ac (where I do the calculation). I messed around with these for a while to no avail.

Comment: Look at the crash, and try to figure out what it means, and fix it.